# Name for the comma in "Jim kept walking, past the streetlight."

Tags: commas

I want to explain to a student why "Jim kept walking past the streetlight" conjures up an image of someone repeatedly walking past the streetlight, and that if the student merely wants to say that Jim passed the streetlight as he continued to walk, he needs a comma: "Jim kept walking, past the streetlight."

Is there a name for this use of a comma? Thank you.

Comment: No, it conjures us: He continued to walk past the streetlight. keep doing something is continue to do something. This question should be on ELL, not here. So, poor old Jim was walking, something happened and then he continued to walk past the streetlight. The comma changes nothing.

Comment: There is no name for a comma usage there. You decide to put it in or not.

Comment: The comma merely helps determine how phrases are grouped. Without the comma, "walking past the streetlight" is a single verb phrase, and "kept" modifies it as something repeated. With the comma, the verb is only "walking", and "past the streetlight qualifies" the whole phrase.

Comment: This is the *pause for clarity* use of this favorite, flexible, and multi-functional piece of punctuation.

Comment: I would use a dash (or perhaps a colon) if  more follows, e.g. "Jim kept walking—past the streetlight, around the corner, and into the bar. The pause here feels longer than a comma.

Comment: The comma marks nonessential (parenthetical) content. *John kept walking (past the streetlight, under the bridge, and up the stairs).* Compare *John kept walking around the block.*

Comment: Yes; as TH says, this is a parenthetical-offsetting comma. Compare << Jim kept walking (past the streetlight) until he reached the junction. The parenthetical is such an aside that offsetting commas now don't really work too well – but note that the medial parenthetical needs offsets at each end. The original has a terminal parenthetical (if the intended meaning is selected) and so brackets or a _single_ dash or comma is applicable. // Without the comma, the non-parenthetical reading prevails as you say: << {Jim} {kept [on]} {walking past the streetlight.} >>

Comment: Punctuation matters. My favorite example: "Don't! Stop!" versus "Don't stop!"